# Chromium suddenly started creating redundant '~' directory inside home directory. How to get rid of it?

Tags: linux, configuration, chrome, home, troubleshooting

A mysterious `'~'` directory recently appeared inside my home directory (as in `~/~`). Inside I found a single hidden directory `.confit` which contained a single directory `chromium`. Inside that `~/~/.confit/chromium` directory were several of the same contents as `~/.config/chromium`. I have been using Chromium for years and this is the first time I have seen this behavior. Has anyone else encountered this? I can delete the `'~'` directory but it comes back every time I launch Chromium. I wish I could identify exactly when it started, but I have already deleted it several times and I don't remember exactly when it first appeared. What determines where Chromium saves its config files? server-side settings? source code? I don't even know where to look. I'm running Arch Linux in case that matters.

Edit: Is it possible that the error could be in my configs for an Electron app rather than Chromium itself?

Edit: `$CHROME_CONFIG_HOME` is not set and I set `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` to `/home/(my username)/.config` when I was first troubleshooting this issue. It didn't change anything.

Comment: Check your environment (`env`) for anything with `~` in the value.

Comment: If you use `~` in any of the dotfiles, it may need to be replaced with `$HOME`.

Comment: It's not only the initial `~` but also the `confit` where `t` is close to `g` on the keyboard, and this is an indication for a typo while doing some activity, for example like [this](https://www.chromium.org/developers/creating-and-using-profiles). Also it seems that no other program is writing anything under that directory, so I don't expect this issue to come from a system global variable but from something Chromium specific.

Comment: Also see here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/62.0.3202.58/docs/user_data_dir.md#linux and report if you have set `$CHROME_CONFIG_HOME` and `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`.

Comment: *What determines where Chromium saves its config files?* See link above. It is a configurable setting for the program. The default value is `~/.config` but also it is allowed to be overwritten.

Comment: what about a bruteforce approach? `fgrep -r .confit ~` ?

Comment: That bruteforce approach would have saved me a lot of time, I'll have to remember that for next time. What I ended up doing was a more manual version of the same thing, using grep file by file. I guess I should learn my tools better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. User error sure enough. My i3 config file was the culprit. I had keybindings set to launch chromium with flag `--user-data-dir=~/.confit/chromium/...` Really obvious in hindsight. Changed it to `--user-data-dir=$HOME/.config/chromium/...` and it works correctly now. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Apart from the typo, the problem is that even if the command is launched through a shell, the tilde won't be expanded there, in the middle of a word. Bash would expand it after the `=` in something that "looks like" a shell assignment. But `--foo=~/bar` doesn't fit that because the dashes aren't valid in a shell variable name.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mention that in my original answer. Updated it now. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: When I try to use a data-dir in a path with a '.' in it, I get `Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory.`  `snap run chromium --user-data-dir=$HOME/foo/chromium-W3C/` works, but `mv foo .foo; snap run chromium --user-data-dir=$HOME/.foo/chromium-W3C/` fails.
I'm jealous that you get to use the customary `.config` dir.